# How to serve sitemap.xml from outside project folder in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a `Spring Boot 2 Web application` which is a blogging website, where I have a dynamic `sitemap.xml` file. The `sitemap.xml` gets updated whenever we add a new article in the repository. Now I need to serve the `sitemap.xml` file from outside of the project location. Consider the `sitemap.xml` is present in the following location:

```
/home/admin/sitemap.xml
```

My requirement is, whenever a user hit the url `https://<my_url>/sitemap.xml` then the file should be served from the mentioned location. I have added the mapping for the same.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/sitemap.xml/**").addResourceLocations("/home/admin/sitemap.xml");
    }
}
```

But the code is not working. Can anyone suggest that, what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this by writing a `GetMapping`. Many solutions on the internet are saying that to return the `sitemap.xml` file as a `String`. But please note **Google will not read that** `sitemap.xml` file for the wrong `Content-Type` header. The `Content-Type` must be **`"application/xml"`**. Following is my `@GetMapping`

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml")
    public void serveSiteMapFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/home/admin/sitemap.xml")))) {
            String line;
            StringBuilder siteMapBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                siteMapBuilder.append(line);
            }
            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.println(siteMapBuilder.toString());
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
```